# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: globalInfo.map is not a function JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hi i have a problem with display Data From API using Fetch.

when I try to extract the function "Map ()" Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: globalInfo.map is not a function"

Below I am pasting the code.

```js
fetch('https://coinpaprika1.p.rapidapi.com/global', target)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((globalInfo) => {
        infos = globalInfo.map((info) => {
           return {
                mcap: market_cap_usd.info
                volume: volume_24h_usd.info
           }
        })
     })
```

> Object { market_cap_usd: 1020943415527, volume_24h_usd: 69817864918, bitcoin_dominance_percentage: 37.14, cryptocurrencies_number: 8297, market_cap_ath_value: 3629384273801, market_cap_ath_date: "2021-10-27T07:40:00Z", volume_24h_ath_value: 2461621335224, volume_24h_ath_date: "2022-03-26T03:05:00Z", volume_24h_percent_from_ath: -97.16, volume_24h_percent_to_ath: 3425.78, … }
> ​
> bitcoin_dominance_percentage: 37.14
> ​
> cryptocurrencies_number: 8297
> ​
> last_updated: 1662299758
> ​
> market_cap_ath_date: "2021-10-27T07:40:00Z"
> ​
> market_cap_ath_value: 3629384273801
> ​
> market_cap_change_24h: 0.04
> ​
> market_cap_usd: 1020943415527
> ​
> volume_24h_ath_date: "2022-03-26T03:05:00Z"
> ​
> volume_24h_ath_value: 2461621335224
> ​
> volume_24h_change_24h: -26.74
> ​
> volume_24h_percent_from_ath: -97.16
> ​
> volume_24h_percent_to_ath: 3425.78
> ​
> volume_24h_usd: 69817864918
> ​
> : Object { … }

Comment: Seems like the problem here is that you are applying `.map` for non array element, I guess to an `Object` in this case.

Comment: Could you provide the json response in a more clear way? Is like this `[...]` or like this `{...}`?

Comment: ohhh god... thanks, its {..} - Object... but can i do something with this? i mean to put into a array?  [..]

Comment: Of course you can, but it depends on the structure of that json, so it would be very helpful that you share the structure of that response. For example, if its a big object with a bunch of key/value pairs in wich the values are the objects that you need you could go with something like `infos = Object.values(globalInfo)`. This would save in `infos` all the objects that you need, but like I said before, in order to get you a complete answer we have to see that response.

Comment: it's something like this:

{
  "market_cap_usd": 1024793028471,
  "volume_24h_usd": 71361981113,
  "bitcoin_dominance_percentage": 37.17,
  "cryptocurrencies_number": 8659,
  "market_cap_ath_value": 3629384273801,
  "market_cap_ath_date": "2021-10-27T07:40:00Z",
  "volume_24h_ath_value": 2461621335224,
  "volume_24h_ath_date": "2022-03-26T03:05:00Z",
  "volume_24h_percent_from_ath": -97.1,
  "volume_24h_percent_to_ath": 3349.49,
  "market_cap_change_24h": 0.78,
  "volume_24h_change_24h": -4.48,
  "last_updated": 1662325678
}

Comment: just 2 values Key: market_cap_usd and value for this 1024793028471

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```js
fetch('https://coinpaprika1.p.rapidapi.com/global', target)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((globalInfo) => {
    return { 
      mcap: globalInfo.market_cap_usd
      volume: globalInfo.volume_24h_usd
    }
  })
```

Please, confirm if that is working.

Comment: works fine :)  Thanks a lot man. you are my hero xD